# What did "sysctl vm" do?

Tags: command-line, kernel, lubuntu

My system: Linux/Lubuntu 18.04 LTS, 64 bit

What I *wanted to do* was checking the value of my swappiness with the terminal-command

```
sysctl vm.swappiness
```

Out of sheer clumsiness I only typed

```
sysctl vm
```

and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The thing is: I got output after all:

```
rosika@rosika-Lenovo-H520e ~> sysctl vm
vm.admin_reserve_kbytes = 8192
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.compact_unevictable_allowed = 1
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.dirtytime_expire_seconds = 43200
vm.drop_caches = 0
vm.extfrag_threshold = 500
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 256   256 32  1
vm.max_map_count = 65530
vm.memory_failure_early_kill = 0
vm.memory_failure_recovery = 1
vm.min_free_kbytes = 67584
vm.min_slab_ratio = 5
vm.min_unmapped_ratio = 1
vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536
sysctl: Zugriff verweigert auf Schlüssel »vm.mmap_rnd_bits«
sysctl: Zugriff verweigert auf Schlüssel »vm.mmap_rnd_compat_bits«
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_hugepages_mempolicy = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
vm.numa_stat = 1
vm.numa_zonelist_order = Node
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.stat_interval = 1
sysctl: Zugriff verweigert auf Schlüssel »vm.stat_refresh«
vm.swappiness = 60
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 121890
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
vm.watermark_scale_factor = 10
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0
rosika@rosika-Lenovo-H520e ~> echo $status 
255
```

Yet, as you can see, I got exit-code 255.

So can someone tell me what I have done? I hope it wasn´t something too silly after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK all your command did was print *every* `variable = value` pair from the `/proc/sys/vm` namespace instead of just that of `vm.swappiness` - essentially the equivalent of having done `cat /proc/sys/vm/*` instead of `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`.

To have actually changed any parameters, you would have needed to add `-w` or `--write` (and specified a particular one, and likely to have elevated your privileges as well).

Comment: Tnx a lot for your answer and good explanation. That sounds reassuring. I certainly didn´t add `-w` or `--write`. So everything should be fine.